# What are those *.nar, *.thm and *.tnl files in my Pictures folder? Can delete them?

Tags: camera, 8.1-update-1

See picture below:

[image: Files in my picture folder]

I saw this file when I browse to my Pictures folder via USB.

I can imagine that the file suffixed with `_Rich.nar` is related with the *Rich Capture* feature in Lumia Camera 5 and the files `*.thm` and `*.tnl` are the *Living Images* but I don't know for sure.

- What are those files exactly?
- What happen if I delete them?
- Can I use them in other softwares instead of in the phone?

Comment: Well I've deleted those files and my pictures haven't died, but don't go by that :). I don't think deleting any of them should affect your pictures (e.g. .thm is a thumbnail file: http://fileinfo.com/extension/thm ).

Comment: @Shawn Hum, I don't think that file indo apply. Impossible to be just a thumb with 986KB. But at least good to hear that they are not essential.

Comment: If you delete the NAR you can't re-edit photos on the phone. E.g. in Rich Capture or Refocus apps you can go back and edit the photo from the multiple exposures or focus that the camera shot. The NAR is basically the original photo data. Although WP doesn't upload these to OneDrive annoyingly and once it's uploaded the JPEG edits on the phone aren't re-synced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are files created by the Lumia camera app to provide certain features that are not possible with standard jpeg files. While the .thm and .tnl files are simple preview files for your movies (the small image you see in your pictures folder) the .nar includes things like living images or the data to refocus your picture.

You can open the .nar like a simple ZIP Archive and explore the contents. Some image viewers should be able to show the preview files.

So if you just want to keep that single picture or movie you can safely delete the rest.

- [*.nar](http://dotwhat.net/file/extension/nar/10995)

  > Created by Nokia devices, these files are stored in Nokia's Camera
  >   File (NAR) format and are zipped container files that hold multiple
  >   .jpg files and an .xml meta data file.
- [*.thm](http://dotwhat.net/file/extension/thm/5314)

  > A thumb nail image is similar in size to an icon image and is used to
  >   represent a larger image. Thumbnail images are often used on the
  >   internet or in photo/clip-art galleries.
- [*.tnl](http://dotwhat.net/file/extension/tnl/7387)

  > Files which are given the .TNL extension are known as Thumbnail image
  >   format files, however other file types may also use this extension.

Comment: So ca I delete them safely if I just want the pictures?

Comment: yes you can delete them safely if you want only images

Comment: So why can you not copy these files onto your computer? Moving pictures to computer I get "Error while moving “WP_NAME_Smart.nar” a bunch of times. Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Hm, works on a Windows machine ^^ have you tried copying the files instead of moving them?

Answer (score 11):

Like the original poster said in a comment, the information on FileInfo hasn't been updated to take Windows Phone cameras into consideration.

**.nar**: 
Like Thomas answered, the *.nar files are basically renamed *.zip files that include extra pictures, photo data, etc, and are related to Lumia Refocus and Rich Capture.

**.thm** and **.tnl**: These two files are related to the Living Image feature. If you set file extensions to be visible, you'll notice that Living Images always come in a trio of files when working properly:

- WP_datestamp_Pro.jpg: This is of course the actual picture.
- WP_datestamp_Pro.mp4.thm: Notice the extra **.mp4** in the file name. This is the actual living image, and is packaged as an .mp4 with an added file extension to differentiate from the videos that your camera takes.
- WP_datestamp_Pro.mp4.tnl: This is, as noted above, the thumbnail for your Living Image video. This will also appear for actual videos that you take with the normal .mp4 extension. Occasionally, you'll see a .jpg with an associated .tnl but no .thm, meaning the Living Images messed up and never recorded a video; I personally delete those, as they are unnecessary.

If your phone saves in higher resolutions and your settings allow it, there will be a fourth file:

- WP_datestamp_Pro_highres.jpg: This is the full resolution picture. For example, if the settings are set to capture JPEG (5MP + 16MP), the first .jpg will be 5MP and the highres.jpg will be 16MP.

Also note, with Windows 10, the format has changed a bit. Living Images are now embedded in the .jpg instead of a separate file, though I can't quite explain as I haven't had much experience with them.

Sources:

- [Information on Living Images in Windows Phone 8.1](http://forums.windowscentral.com/ask-question/321846-viewing-living-images-pc.html)
- [Information on Living Images in Windows 10 Mobile](http://forums.windowscentral.com/guides-tips-tricks-how-tos/400251-how-view-windows-10-mobile-living-images-your-pc.html)
- [Information on Rich Capture in Windows 10 Mobile](http://forums.windowscentral.com/guides-tips-tricks-how-tos/400252-adjust-windows-10-mobile-rich-capture-lighting-your-pc.html) (Same as Windows Phone 8.1)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Is there a simple way how to convert the WP8.1 Living images files to the new Win10 format? I have a lot of Living images on my Lumia 930 and would love to be able to "play" them in the new Win10 Photos app.